# Function not assigning value

Tags: c

This is just a part of my code, I don't get any errors on it, but it appears that function `register_user` doesn't assign values properly.

Is it because `strcpy(user[n].username, username);` and `user[n].age = user[n].age + age;` are not correct?

I realize that the values could've been easily assigned to array with `gets(user->username);` and `scanf("%d", &user->age);`, but I'm trying to do it this other way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char username[30];
    int age;
} User;

int functions() {
    int option;
    printf("\n");
    printf("1. Register\n");
    printf("2. Display all users\n");

    printf("Choose a function: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    getchar();

    return option;
}

void display_user(const User user) {
    printf("\n");
    printf("Username: %s\n", user.username);
    printf("Age : %d\n", user.age);
}

void register_user(User *user, int n) {
    int i, age;
    char username[30];
    
    printf("\nUsername: ");
    scanf("%s", username);
    printf("Age : ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    strcpy(user[n].username , username);
    user[n].age = user[n].age + age;

    printf("\nRegistration complete\n");

    }

void display_all_users(const User user[], const int n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        display_user(user[i]);
    }
}


int main()
{
    User users[100];
    User user;
    int n = 0;

    while (1) {
        int option = functions();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                register_user(&user, n);
                users[n++] = user;
                break;
            case 2:
                display_all_users(users, n);
                break;  
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable "array" is not actually an array, it's just a User. So `array[n].age = ...` will not work unless n=0.

Comment: @PaulHankin, in function `register()`, the `array` variable is a `User *`.  `array[n].age` will work fine with that (given the corresponding actual argument) as long as `n` is 0.

Comment: The code presented doesn't compile I think. `main {..}` isn't valid, and there's no type on the `n` parameter.

Comment: Please post real code as [mcve] and not some manufactured fake code that does not even compile.

Comment: I think we need a minimal reproducible example, including input to make sense of the question...

Comment: How do you "display everything inside `array`"?  Please present a [mre] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit it and add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The other problems with this code are a potential buffer overflow if a username longer than 29 characters is entered, and the age field is added-to, but never initialized, and there's no return in register. Is it valid to call a function "register", or is that a reserved word?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change these in order for it to work properly. What I did previously was incorrect.

```
   //strcpy(user[n].username , username); - wrong
   strcpy(user->username , username); //correct

   //user[n].age = user[n].age + age; - wrong
   user->age = age; //correct
```